# Flutter having multiple floatingActionButtons

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have multiple floatingActionButtons on a page in a flutter app, but I haven't been able to solve myself as the instructions on the internet aren't clear.  I want the floating action buttons to be on the bottom right of the app.  The current code correctly has two floatingactionbuttons, but they appear at the top right.  Can someone please let me know how to do this.  Thanks!  Here is my curret code that puts two floatingactionbuttons in the top right but I want them in the bottomright.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "btn1",
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            list.add(list.length);
          });
        }),
        FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "btn2",
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              list.add(list.length);
            });
          }),
      ]), //column end
```

Comment: Maybe makes sense in your app but this practice is discourage by material design https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/. If you still want to do so, use a Column with both buttons as children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:80),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "btn1",
            onPressed: (){},
            child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),),
        ),),

        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "btn2",
            onPressed: (){},
          child: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),),
        ),
      ],
      )
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas Lima da Silva! I made a small correction but this is the correct answer.

Comment: That's it ! Thanks =D